# Show message to close browser or tab but not show in refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used the `onbeforeunload` function to show a message when the browser or tab closes.
It's working and a message shows once you close the page.
The problem is that it is currently also showing up when the page is refreshed, and I only want to show this message on close.
Is there anybody that has a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

No solution for this. A page is refresh and unload the DOM so the `onbeforeunload` event will always be called.